# Converting variables values into a single string and back out

Tags: java, string

There are sometimes where I want to convert several variables into a string to send via a message or method.

For example,
If I have these variables:

```
int addressNum = 223;
String stName = "Main St";
String city = "Chicago";
```

How would I covert it to a single string `"223; Main St; Chicago"` and back to the variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a delimiter of some sort `(, :)`

```
String fullAddress+=addressNum+":"+stName+":"+city;
```

Later on, split the fullAddress based on the delimiter used.

```
String[] arr = fullAddress.split(":");
int addressNumber = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
String streetName = arr[1];
String cityName = arr[2];
```

Comment: `addressNum` is an int though.

Comment: @squiguy if you mean, while retriving it back you can convert it back to int using Integer.parseInt()

Comment: Yes, just thought I would point that out :)

Comment: I am always amazed how quickly answers are given here.  This should do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
String oneLine = addressNum + "; " + stName + "; " + city; - make it in sinle line

// split it to variables below
String[] arr = oneLine.split(";");
addressNum = Integer.parseString(arr[0].trim());
stName = arr[1].trim();
city = arr[2].trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to String, write a wrapper class that holds the data:

```
public class SomeWrapper
{
    int addressNum;
    String stName;
    String city;

    // constructors, setters and getters
}
```

Then use it like:

```
SomeWrapper w = new SomeWrapper(223, "Main St", "Chicago");
```

and extract it like this:

```
int addressNum = w.getAddressNumber();
String stName = w.getStreetName();
String city = w.getCity();
```

and simply you can pass it to methods like:

```
public static void doSomething(SomeWrapper w)
{
    int addressNum = w.getAddressNumber();
    // ...
}

// ...

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SomeWrapper w = ...;
    doSomething(w);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The encoding you choose must be reversible (bijective).

- String may be quoted
- Fields name may be used : `adress="value"`
- Separator should be well chosen; i.e. it does not appear in "normal" values...
- ...

Using a standard like [JSon](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/&ei=ymouUZn1JMaXhQeAqICYBg&usg=AFQjCNGGFFMez8-PfFoEQP93a7eHFY8ssA&sig2=i7kFTzhZ-HF3Puapflfd9w&bvm=bv.42965579,d.ZG4) or [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) may be a better practice.